# QTextStream write data in file

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm learning QtCreator and having troubles writing data in file. Here's some code :

```
char    *str;
int     i = 1;
QFile outFile("path/to/file/out.txt");
outFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QTextStream out(&outFile);

while (i < rows * 2) {
    str = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit *>(this->getItem(i))->text().toLocal8Bit().data();
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    out << str << "\n";
    i += 2;
}
```

`getItem` returns a `QWidget *` from a `QFormLayout` filled with `QLineEdit` (that explains the dynamic cast). Anyway, when I pass `str` into `std::cout` it works fine, the data is printed, but when I pass `str` into `out`, it writes only the first char of `str` in the file.
I don't get what I'm doing wrong, I really would appreciate any tips.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What do you do to `out` and `outFile` after the loop?

Comment: Nothing, I don't `close` the `outFile` cause Qt does it itself (or did I misunderstand ?)

Comment: you're not learning qt creator. You're learning Qt...

Comment: good point, but useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is a problem: `str = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit *>(this->getItem(i))->text().toLocal8Bit().data();`

`dynamic_cast<QLineEdit *>(this->getItem(i))->` is OK
`->text()` creates a temporary `QString`
`.toLocal8Bit()` creates a temporary `QByteArray`
`.data()` returns a pointer to the internal data of the `QByteArray`

As soon as the line is passed the QByteArray will be destroyed and you have a dangling pointer. `str` points to invalid data.

Everything you do with this pointer afterwards (except letting it point to somewhere else) is undefined behaviour.

Try to use something like this:

```
int     i = 1;
QFile outFile("path/to/file/out.txt");
outFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QTextStream out(&outFile);
while (i < rows * 2) 
{
    QLineEdit* lineEdit = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit *>(this->getItem(i));
    if (lineEdit)
    {
        QByteArray str = lineEdit->text().toLocal8Bit();
        std::cout << str.data() << std::endl;
        out << str.data() << "\n";
        i += 2;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Item at " << i << " is no QLineEdit*" << std::endl;
    }
}
out.close();
```

Also please check whether `QFile` is actually open and whether `QTextStream` reports some errors when writing.

Comment: Thank's a lot, that was the problem. But I still don't get why my code prints the wanted value for `str` in the console, but not writing it in the file.

Comment: @LongDuZboub Undefined behaviour is undefined. Most probably because the memory of `QByteArray` wasn't overwritten yet.